# Hibernate 5 creates table with ID not marked as IDENTITY

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, db2

I've a set of entities. When using hibernate 4, the tables are created with id columns marked as identity whereas when using hibernate 5, id columns dont get marked as identity and the sequences are generated as well.

When using hibernate 5 with preexisting database objects and validate setting, application fails saying sequences are not present even though tables have id columns marked as identity.

Why there is this difference in behavior between hibernate 5 and 4?

Is it possible to migrate to hibernate 5 without changing entities and the preexisting database objects?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [Migration Guides](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/5.0/migration-guide.adoc), Hibernate 5 has switched to the new identifier generators.

One side effect is that, for `GenerationType.AUTO` what used to be IDENTITY as default identifier, now you get the TABLE identifier instead. Check out the [HHH-11014](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11014) Jiraa issue for more details.

Now, to use the old identifier generators, you can just set the `hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings` configuration property to `false`:

```
<property 
    name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings"
    value="false"
/>
```

That should do it.